# Will a row still be written even if 'ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column' error occurs?

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

When I put in a number of a certain size and submit the form I get the ORA-01438 error. It seems all of the documents are written to the db but I can't be sure. Maybe the error is occurring in a POST that I am not privy to?

Additional Context: Site gives a 500 error and I am forced to return to the home page to do anything else. When I try to do another form submission I get a hibernate error stating:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for collection: com.collection.name.here

Answer (score 0):

A quick test: table contains two columns; one is `varchar2(2)`, another is `number(2)`:

```
SQL> create table test (col_c varchar2(2), col_n number(2));

Table created.
```

Insert a **string** longer than 2 characters:

```
SQL> insert into test (col_c) values ('abc');
insert into test (col_c) values ('abc')
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCOTT"."TEST"."COL_C" (actual: 3,
maximum: 2)
```

Insert a **number**:

```
SQL> insert into test (col_n) values (123);
insert into test (col_n) values (123)
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

Both raised an error. You said that

> It seems all of the documents are written to the db but I can't be sure

Well, check it! How? By selecting from a table.

```
SQL> select * from test;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Nope, nothing was inserted, so I'd put my bet to the same outcome in your case. If error was raised, your insert failed.

---

As of Hibernate issues, no idea; I don't know Hibernate.